# Translate Chinese Seals (Characters identified: 石渠定鑑 乾隆)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I am attempting to find out the seals of a painting I have. I’ve researched for many hours and am not able to come to any certain conclusions. Really hoping someone is an to help me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first seal means the painting belongs to the royal collection of the Qing Dynasty. The second seal is a name seal of a king of Qing Dynasty